# why are common-lisp functions unbound when I evaluate them individually

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

why does

```
(floor 4.5)
```

return 4 and 0.5 but

```
floor
```

gives an error:

```
The variable FLOOR is unbound.
[Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

Note: I come from a clojure background

How would I be able to access the actual `floor` procedure?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Common Lisp has two different namespaces, one for functions and one for normal variables; scheme (and clojuree, I think) have one namespace. Basically, in Common Lisp defun puts things in a different place than let.

Comment: What okaram is correct. Common Lisp is called a Lisp-2 for this reason, while Scheme is called a Lisp-1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp-1_vs._Lisp-2#The_function_namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use parentheses, like in your first example: `(floor ...)` Common Lisp recognizes it as a list and because it's unquoted, it evaluates it. The first form in an evaluated list must be a function name, a macro name or a special form.

In your second example, you did not use parentheses, so it is not treated as a list, therefore CL tries to interpret it as a variable (variables and functions are in different namespaces).

Try typing `(floor)`, you'll get different error message (invalid number of arguments).

You can access the function namespace by typing

> `#'floor`

or

> `(function floor)`

(these are essentially the same).

Comment: Note that `#'floor` is converted at read-time to `(function floor)` so they're exactly the same, with a normally-configured read-table in place.

Answer (score 2):

```
#'floor
```

Common Lisp keeps variables and functions in different namespaces.